# Are there common reasons one person's Fastlane session works in a CI pipeline, but another's does not?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane

When trying to build and sign an app in our CI pipeline, we currently have to update the Fastlane session environment variable on a daily basis, or it defaults to prompting two factor authentication.

I'm trying to switch the Apple account we're using Fastlane with to my own, as the person's who we currently use is leaving the team.

This should be an easy process as we have the environment variables:

```
FASTLANE_USERNAME
SIGH_USERNAME
FASTLANE_PASSWORD
FASTLANE_SESSION
FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD
```

So in theory, I just switch out their account variables for my own, and replace the session I just generated with:

```
fastlane spaceauth -u <my-email>
```

However when I run the pipeline with the updated env variables pointing to my account, it defaults to two factor authentication without returning an error. When I switch the variables back over to my colleague's account everything works just fine (with the exception of surprisingly short fastlane session lifetime).

Is anyone aware of what might be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was linking my apple developer account to my team account